# Python Mayavi surface plot: error when ploting axes

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am using Mayavi on python2.7 to plot a 3d surface. The problem arises when trying to add the axes to the 3D plot invoking the function mlab.axes().

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1, 1, 1))
s = mlab.surf(x, y, z_func, extent=(0,1, 0,1, 0,1))
mlab.outline(s, extent=(0,1, 0,1, 0,1))
ax = mlab.axes(s, extent=(0,1, 0,1, 0,1))
```

Using this code i am able to view and interact with the surface plot, but the code raises an exception related with the function axes().

This is the error i am getting when running the script:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "mayavi.core.common"
Exception occurred in traits notification handler.
Please check the log file for details.
Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object: <mayavi.tools.decorations.Axes object at 0x7f521d6a3230>, trait: extent, old value: [0 0 0 0 0 0], new value: [0 1 0 1 0 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traits/trait_notifiers.py", line 340, in __call__
    self.handler( *args )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/decorations.py", line 373, in _extent_changed
    axes.module_manager.source.outputs[0].bounds
AttributeError: 'PolyDataNormals' object has no attribute 'bounds'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste3.py", line 47, in <module>
    test_surf()
  File "teste3.py", line 36, in test_surf
    ax = mlab.axes(s2, extent=(0,1, 0,1, 0,1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/pipe_base.py", line 38, in the_function
    factory = factory_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/decorations.py", line 309, in __init__
    SingletonModuleFactory.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/decorations.py", line 264, in __init__
    self.set(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/pipe_base.py", line 179, in set
    callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/tools/decorations.py", line 373, in _extent_changed
    axes.module_manager.source.outputs[0].bounds
AttributeError: 'PolyDataNormals' object has no attribute 'bounds'
```

Also, the following window reporting the exception is presented:
[Mayavi/vtk surface plot axes() error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1ahI.png)

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I get the same error. Very annoying

Comment: Looks like this may have been fixed here: https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/commit/4a29e998742ac16bdfd79e73fcb53807fc6f30b5